# Dynamic rendering of Lightning Data Table

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-datatable

I am trying to  show/hide Lightning data table based on the data receieved.

Based on {`hasApprovedSlots`} true or false I am trying to display the datatable. It is returning true successfully but not false. Meaning it doesn't hide the datatable when the condition(ApprovedSlots has valid value) is false.

```
 <template if:true={hasApprovedSlots}> 
  {hasApprovedSlots}
  <lightning-datatable 
  key-field="Id"
  columns={columns}
  data = {ApprovedSlots}
  min-column-width=200
  hide-checkbox-column>
  </lightning-datatable> 

</template>

export default class pds_GuidedActions_Comp extends LightningElement {

@api   ApprovedSlots=null;

@track columns = [   
        { label: 'Spot Name', fieldName: 'Appointment_Name__c' },
        { label: 'Continuing Care Adult or Child', 
        cellAttributes:{
            iconName:{fieldName:'Continuing_Care_Adult_or_Child__c'}, iconPosition:'right'
        }        
        },
        { label: 'Delivery', 
        cellAttributes:{
            iconName:{fieldName:'Delivery__c'}, iconPosition:'right'
        }
        },
        { label: 'Emergency',
        cellAttributes:{
            iconName:{fieldName:'Emergency__c'}, iconPosition:'right'
        }
        },
        { label: 'Limited Exam (Pt with an issue)',
        cellAttributes:{
            iconName:{fieldName:'Limited_Exam__c'}, iconPosition:'right'
        }
        },
        { label: 'Office Visit (Existing GP non-exam;)',
        cellAttributes:{
            iconName:{fieldName:'Office_Visit__c'}, iconPosition:'right'
        }
        },
        { label: 'Online Teledentistry Visit',
        cellAttributes:{
            iconName:{fieldName:'Online_Teledentistry_Visit__c'}, iconPosition:'right'
        }
        },
        { label: 'Sealants',
        cellAttributes:{
            iconName:{fieldName:'Sealants__c'}, iconPosition:'right'
        }    
        },
        { label: 'Sealants with Nitrous',
        cellAttributes:{
            iconName:{fieldName:'Sealants_with_Nitrous__c'}, iconPosition:'right'
        }
        },
        { label: 'Treatment Patients',
        cellAttributes:{
            iconName:{fieldName:'Treatment_Patients__c'}, iconPosition:'right'
        }
        },
        { label: 'Treatment Patients with Nitrous',
        cellAttributes:{
            iconName:{fieldName:'Treatment_Patients_with_Nitrous__c'}, iconPosition:'right'
        }
        },
        
    ];

    @wire(MessageContext)
    messageContext;

get hasApprovedSlots(){
    return (this.ApprovedSlots !==null) && (this.ApprovedSlots !==undefined) && (this.ApprovedSlots !=="") ? true:false; 
}
    
connectedCallback() {
        if (!this.subscription) {
            this.subscription = subscribe(
                this.messageContext,
                picklistValue,
                (message) => this.handlePicklistKey(message)
            );
        }
    }

    handlePicklistKey(message) {                     
        this.recivedMsg = message;
        if(this.recivedMsg !== null){ 
            this.boolVisible = true;          
            if(this.recivedMsg.ApprovedSlots !== null || this.recivedMsg.ApprovedSlots !== undefined){                
                this.LogcallID = this.recivedMsg.ApprovedSlots;
                this.getAppmntSlots();
                if (this.recivedMsg.OfficeFieldSet !== null || this.recivedMsg.OfficeFieldSet !== undefined) {            
                    this.OfficeFieldSet = this.recivedMsg.OfficeFieldSet;
                    this.getOffData();
                }                
            }                          
            else{
                this.boolVisible = false;
                this.ApprovedSlots=null;
            }
            delete this.recivedMsg;
        }
    }

    //get appointment chart table
    getAppmntSlots(){ 
        fetchChartValues({
            logId: this.LogcallID
        })
            .then((data) => {               
                this.ApprovedSlots = data;                                
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error',error);
            });            
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try by adding logs in hasApprovedSlots getter to check. Also , you do not need to add so many conditions for invalid check.
Just add - (!!this.ApprovedSlots && this.ApprovedSlots?.length> 0) and it will take care of all the conditions.

Comment: Also , this.ApprovedSlots is an array . Initialise it as : 
@api ApprovedSlots = [];